# Google Places API: Text Search with My Location

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am getting my head around the Google Places APi.

I am using TextSearch and it generally seems ok. However, the responses are not quite what I want.

here is my search: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Reading&sensor=true&key=XxXXXXXXXXMYKEY

The search above responds with REading, PA then Reading UK, however as I am in Reading UK I would expect reading UK to be returned first.

So, I want to get results ordered my my Location (however I don't want to limit my results to 50KM radius), is there are knowledge out there for how to do this? (Without doing my own distance ordering....)

Thanks
Aiden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `location` and `radius` parameters to your request. For example:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Reading&sensor=true&location=51.508315,-0.123013&radius=50000&key=your_api_key

This will bias results within the specified radius over ones outside however, if a result is not available within the radius will be ignored and the next best match will be returned.

For more information please read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#TextSearchRequests).

Comment: Hah i was looking at that documentation no idea how i missed the location parameter! Thanks.